# How to Resolve eglDestroySurface?

Tags: android, development-environment

I'm currently creating new project in android studio. While create new task relative layout, the instant preview show accurate result of xml coding.
while running it on emulator shows nothing except empty screen

**The following error occurred in logcat panel**

> 09-09 10:48:18.879  23035-23035/com.topitideas.todoekspert W/PGA﹕
>   [23035] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557b07a0, 0x0, 0x7856b138,
>   0x7756d0e0) 09-09 10:48:18.889  23035-23035/com.topitideas.todoekspert
>   W/PGA﹕ [23035] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x557b07a0, 0x0,
>   0x7856b138, 0x7756d0e0) returned

Kindly help me and teach me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You may post your xml code of the layout.

Comment: But how to post it ?

Comment: You can copy paste the code from the Android Studio